# Why is the reported number of hits from elasticsearch different depending on the query method?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index which has 60k elements. I know that by checking the `head` plugin and I get the same information via [Sense](https://www.found.no/foundation/Sense-Elasticsearch-interface/) (the result is in the lower right corner)

[image]

I then wanted to query the same index from Python, in two diffrent ways: via a direct `requests` call and using the `elasticsearch` module:

```
import elasticsearch
import json
import requests

# the requests version
data = {"query": {"match_all": {}}}
r = requests.get('http://elk.example.com:9200/nessus_current/_search', data=json.dumps(data))
print(len(r.json()['hits']['hits']))

# the elasticsearch module version
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(hosts='elk.example.com')
res = es.search(index="nessus_current", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
print(len(res['hits']['hits']))
```

In both cases the result is `10` - far from the expected 60k. The results of the query make sense (the content is what I expect), it is just that there are only a few of them.

I took one of these 10 hits and queried with Sense for its `_id` to close the loop. It is, as expected, found indeed:

[image]

So it looks like the 10 hits are a subset of the whole index, why aren't all elements reported in the Python version of the calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[10 is the default size of the results returned by Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html). If you want more, specify `"size": 100` for example. But, be careful, returning all the docs using size is not recommended as it can bring down your cluster. For getting back all the results use [scan&scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html).

And I think it should be `res['hits']['total']` not `res['hits']['hits']` to get the number of total hits.

Comment: you are correct, shame on me: I used some similar code before and totally forgot about the default size (I also used scrolling). I used `len(res['hits']['hits'])` so that part of the code at least is OK :). Thanks!